# RPostgreSQL access to database, error: unable to find an inherited method for function "show", for signature "PostgreSQLConnection"

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

This is a new one, and I have not found any mentions of this on other stackoverflow sites.

So I am programming in R and using the RPostgreSQL package to access a Postgres 9.1.5 database. So I created the connection to the database as I would normally do it, and now I am getting a strange error.

```
db.conn = function(){

  ## This function creates a connection to the database. Subsequent
  ## functions that access the db will go through this function.
  drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con = dbConnect(drv, user = "user", password = "password", dbname = "dbname", host = "localhost", port = 5432)
  return(con)
}
```

so when I create an object:

```
testdb = db.conn()
```

The object seems to get created, but when I type

```
testdb

Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "show", for signature "PostgreSQLConnection"
```

I have never seen this error before. Any suggestions on where it might be coming from? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not cross-post. I just replied on the RPostgreSQL list too, saying that this works just fine for me:

```
R> library(RPostgreSQL)
Loading required package: DBI
R> drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL") 
R> con <- dbConnect(drv, user = "edd", password = ".....", dbname = "......",
+                   host = "localhost", port = 5432)
R> con
<PostgreSQLConnection:(21267,0)> 
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Dirk. Hmm, I am still getting the error, but it seems like the connection object is working fine. I am wondering if it might have to do with my version of Postgresql? But anyway, it seems like this is not an issue now. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and adding the parameters you mention does nothing for me.

con <- dbConnect(dbDriver('PostgreSQL'), db = '....', user = 'SYSTEM', password='....', host='localhost', port='5432')  

I still get the same error stated by @krishnab above.  The connection was working fine until I started creating users to handle connections from Jenkins correctly.

Comment: ok... for some reason, I cleaned up my workspace, redefined con, and it now prints just fine.

Comment: Good to know -- I was just about to suggest that you post a _reproducible_ example on the mailing list.

Comment: `dbIsValid(con)` returns an error.  Is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

In case this is helpful for others, I received a similar error:

> "unable to find an inherited method for function `dbIsValid` for signature "PostgreSQLConnection"

This happened when I inadvertently forgot to assign the result of my *dbConnect* call to a connection object.

So this did not work:

> dbConnect(...)

but this did:

> con <- dbConnect(...)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours.My solution is to remove the "DBI" package and re-install it. It works for me. But it might not work for you. you can try:

```
remove.packages("DBI")
install.packages("DBI")
```